# Moon illumination percent from moon phase age in Ruby

Tags: ruby, astronomy

I have the following module to calculate some moon properties. Very simple according to [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_phase#Calculating_phase). How do I calculate illumination percent though?

I can make it linear where 100% is the mid of `LUNAR_MONTH`. But I expect it might be incorrect to make it linear due to the oval shape of the body.

Or should it be liner?

```rb
module LunarPhase
  LUNAR_MONTH = 29.530588853
  KNOWN_NEW_MOON = DateTime.new(2000, 1, 6, 6, 14, 0).amjd.to_f

  module ClassMethods
    def percent(time = DateTime.now)
      age(time) / LUNAR_MONTH
    end

    def age(time = DateTime.now)
      (time.amjd - KNOWN_NEW_MOON).abs % LUNAR_MONTH
    end

    def illumination(time = DateTime.now)
      # this is linear but maybe we need something more complicated
      # because I see a difference with online calculators
      age_full = LUNAR_MONTH / 2
      diff = age_full - age(time)
      (age_full - diff.abs) / age_full
    end
  end

  extend ClassMethods
end
```

-- you can use code as [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/)

Update: I see some calculations in [Greg Miller's page](https://www.celestialprogramming.com/meeus-illuminated_fraction_of_the_moon.html) but it is full of constants I don't understand. Some theory behind that would be very useful.

Comment: Maybe better suited for https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/ , leaving the Ruby specific stuff out and using pseudo-code (or no code at all).

Comment: @steenslag makes sense, let me see: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/51505/13912

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little clues from [Greg Miller](https://www.celestialprogramming.com/meeus-illuminated_fraction_of_the_moon.html), I've adapted his routine and this is what I've got.

```rb
require "time"

module LunarPhase
  LUNAR_MONTH = 29.530588853
  JULIAN_YEAR = 365.25
  J2000 = DateTime.new(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0).amjd.to_f
  KNOWN_NEW_MOON = DateTime.new(2000, 1, 6, 6, 14, 0).amjd.to_f

  module ClassMethods
    # credits to https://celestialprogramming.com/meeus-illuminated_fraction_of_the_moon.html
    # some more clues at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_moon
    # rubocop:disable all
    def illumination(time = DateTime.now)
      t = centuries_since_j2000(time)

      d = rad(297.8501921 + 445267.1114034*t - 0.0018819*t*t + 1.0/545868.0*t*t*t - 1.0/113065000.0*t*t*t*t) #47.2
      m = rad(357.5291092 + 35999.0502909*t - 0.0001536*t*t + 1.0/24490000.0*t*t*t) #47.3
      mp = rad(134.9633964 + 477198.8675055*t + 0.0087414*t*t + 1.0/69699.0*t*t*t - 1.0/14712000.0*t*t*t*t) #47.4

      i = rad(180 - d*180/Math::PI - 6.289 * Math.sin(mp) + 2.1 * Math.sin(m) -1.274 * Math.sin(2*d - mp) -0.658 * Math.sin(2*d) -0.214 * Math.sin(2*mp) -0.11 * Math.sin(d)) #48.4
      (1+Math.cos(i))/2
      # rubocop:enable all
    end

    def percent(time = DateTime.now)
      age(time) / LUNAR_MONTH
    end

    def age(time = DateTime.now)
      age_from_known = time.to_datetime.amjd - KNOWN_NEW_MOON
      age_from_known += LUNAR_MONTH if age_from_known.negative?
      age_from_known % LUNAR_MONTH
    end

    def full?(time = DateTime.now)
      illumination(time) > 0.98
    end

    private

    def centuries_since_j2000(time = DateTime.now)
      (time.to_datetime.amjd.to_f - J2000) / (JULIAN_YEAR * 100)
    end

    def rad(num)
      angle = num % 360
      angle += 360 if angle.negative?
      angle * Math::PI / 180
    end
  end

  extend ClassMethods
end
```

As for accuracy, new moon is at

- Jan 6 23:09 according to mooninfo.org
- Jan 6 23:05 according to method above

Comment: You have a 12 hour error because you have the J2000 epoch wrong by about 12 hours (`J2000 = DateTime.new(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)`). The J2000 epoch was 12 noon Terrestrial Time on 1 Jan 2000, or 11:58:55.816 UTC on 1 Jan 2000. It's handy to have the day number increment when normal people are normally sleeping: e.g., midnight. Astronomers aren't normal people. Until very recently, they slept during the day and watched the skies at night. To them, it was handy to have the day number increment at noon, when they were asleep, hence the 12 hour offset.

Comment: @DavidHammen, yes, that is true, now accuracy is within 4 minutes for the next full moon!